# htaccess redirect redirect with a post variable

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'd like to use htaccess to redirect users who come into `vcard.aspx` with a post variable `(www.site.com/vcard/vcard.aspx?id=postvar)` to be redirected to `(www.newsite.com/vcard/vcard.aspx?id=postvar)`.

Answer (score 0):

Stop searching for the answer for this problem as it is **not Possible to transfer POST data while redirecting to a new URL using just mod_rewrite**.